# Can't get sockets to work in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I'm trying to use sockets to send/receive data in ASP.NET Core. I followed a few tutorial I found but I can't seem to get any working. No matter what I try in my website, the socket connector stays in the "Connecting/Opening" state.

These are the tutorials I tried:

- http://zbrad.github.io/tools/wscore/ -> this is the one I currently used in my code below
- https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/aspnet-core-websockets-middleware/
- http://dotnetthoughts.net/using-websockets-in-aspnet-core/

My startup.cs file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using arnvanhoutte.Data;
using arnvanhoutte.Models;
using arnvanhoutte.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace arnvanhoutte
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName);
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true);

            Console.WriteLine(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddUserSecrets("aspnet-arnvanhoutte-8942961e-3f9b-48f6-a54d-907858e0ad3a");
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        private IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/Admin/User/Login");
            });

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<Seed>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Seed seeder)
        {

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

            seeder.SeedRoles().ConfigureAwait(false);
            seeder.SeedAdminUser().ConfigureAwait(false);
            seeder.SeedTestUser().ConfigureAwait(false);



            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.Map("/ws", SocketHandler.Map);

          if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    var request = context.Request;
                    if (request.IsHttps)
                    {
                        await next();
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        var devPort = Configuration.GetValue<int>("iisSettings:iisExpress:sslPort");

                        var host = new HostString(request.Host.Host, devPort);

                        string newUrl = $"https://{host}{request.PathBase}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
                        context.Response.Redirect(newUrl, true);
                    }
                });
            }

            app.UseIdentity();

            // secretKey contains a secret passphrase only your server knows
            var secretKey = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")["SecretKey"];
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

            var options = new TokenProviderOptions
            {
                Path = "/token",
                Audience = "User",
                Issuer = "arnvanhoutte",
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
                IdentityResolver = (username, password) =>
                {
                    using (
                        var serviceScope =
                            app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
                    {
                        var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

                        var user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(username).Result;

                        if (user != null && userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password).Result)
                        {
                            return user;
                        }

                        // Credentials are invalid, or account doesn't exist
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // The signing key must match!
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

                // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "arnvanhoutte",

                // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "User",

                // Validate the token expiry
                ValidateLifetime = true,

                // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
            });

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/login"),
                ReturnUrlParameter = "redirect",
                CookieName = "access_token",
                TicketDataFormat = new CustomJwtDataFormat(
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256,
                    tokenValidationParameters)
            });

            app.UseMiddleware<TokenProviderMiddleware>(Options.Create(options));

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("myProjects",
                    "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    "default",
                    "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the sockethandler.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace arnvanhoutte.Services
{
    public class SocketHandler
    {
        public const int BufferSize = 4096;

        private readonly WebSocket _socket;

        private SocketHandler(WebSocket socket)
        {
            _socket = socket;
        }

        private async Task EchoLoop()
        {
            var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            var seg = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);

            while (_socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var incoming = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(seg, CancellationToken.None);
                var outgoing = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, incoming.Count);
                await _socket.SendAsync(outgoing, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Acceptor(HttpContext hc, Func<Task> n)
        {
            if (!hc.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
                return;

            var socket = await hc.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            var h = new SocketHandler(socket);
            await h.EchoLoop();
        }
        public static void Map(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.Use(Acceptor);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the html file I serve:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div id="output"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var socket;
    var uri = "ws://" + window.location.host + "/ws";
    var output;
    var text = "test echo";

    function write(s) {
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = s;
        output.appendChild(p);
    }

    function doConnect() {
        socket = new WebSocket(uri);
        socket.onopen = function (e) { write("opened " + uri); doSend(); };
        socket.onclose = function (e) { write("closed"); };
        socket.onmessage = function (e) { write("Received: " + e.data); socket.close(); };
        socket.onerror = function (e) { write("Error: " + e.data); };
    }

    function doSend() {
        write("Sending: " + text);
        socket.send(text);
    }

    function onInit() {
        output = document.getElementById("output");
        doConnect();
    }

    window.onload = onInit;

</script>
```

When I run this and navigate to the file, nothing initially appears. After a while do I get this error in the console: `sockettest:17 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:44399/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: Your tutorial links are incorrect.

Comment: @mjwills whoops, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution! The problem was that google chrome was blocking my websockets I think because of an unsafe certificate. The fix was to generate a legit certificate with a script found here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/854

Then I also had to change the uri to `wss://` instead of `ws://`. Then everything worked

Comment: Ok, you are a bit wrong, the problem is that Chrome does not allow to mix HTTP and HTTPS, so if your page is HTTPS you must use SSL websockets (`wss://` instead of `ws://`)

Comment: Yeah but it only gave me that warning after it accepted my certificate. Before it just said nothing and stayed in the opening state

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the `Map` function of the `SocketHandler` class in your `Configure` function of the `Startup` class.

Add this in the `Configure`function:

```
SocketHandler.Map(app);
```

Comment: I added this first at the top of the `Configure` function and then not even the html file came through. However at the end it does send the html file to the browser, however sockets are still not working.

Comment: Have you checked if now the acceptor function is being called when you do a websocket request to the server?

Comment: Well, sorry to read this. I have a working solution with websockets as I use it myself under .net Core, in my solution there is a very big difference, I use Kestrel. If I don't recall it wrong IISExpress had a ton of problems with WebSockets (and by default they're disabled: https://forums.asp.net/t/1828041.aspx?IIS+websocket+module+is+not+enabled), can you try to use Kestrel instead of IISExpress? It's very simple, just add `.UseKestrel()` to the `WebHostBuilder` configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It lead me to finding the answer! It turns out that the problem was that my certificate was not valid in Chrome, so it refused the ws:// connection

Comment: Hmmm, that's very strange, `ws://` is not SSL secured, to be secured it should be `wss://`, so there is no need for a certificate... Anyway I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend you to try **SignalR**. Please follow below link to know more about it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Comment: I looked at SignalR before but it seems like it's not available for ASP.NET Core yet